# How to iterate an array of objects and construct a new array of objects based on a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of objects which look like this.

[image]

**GOAL       : CONSTRUCT AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS BASED ON THE OLD OBJECT**

**CONSTRAINTS:**

**1. It's within the same month**

**2. Group object based on category**

**3. Sum up the amount from each category**

This is how I want my final array to look like

```
[
    {
        category: "001",
        amount: "10",
    },
    {
        category: "002",
        amount: "20",
    },
    {
        category: "004",
        amount: "30.2",
    },
]
```

This is what I got so far

```
expensesObject.forEach((item) => {
  //group item according to month DONE
  if(Moment(item.exactDate).month() === snapIndex) { //snapIndex represents month index

    //construct new object according to category

    //push object to new array
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you post your original object as code instead of a screenshot please ?

Comment: What do you mean by **It's within the same month** ? In the same month compared to now ? If the item is more than one month old, we don't count it ?

Comment: have you checked using .reduce() ?
You can use objects as accumumulated values, as well

Comment: What happens if it's in the same category, but not the same month?

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, I only want to collect data from the same month user selected in the app, I already sorted that out.

Comment: @TimConsolazio then it will not be considered :)

Comment: Alight, which one do you leave out, how would you know? If I have a month 03 and 04, both in category 0001, which one gets discarded?

Comment: @J.Doe Thus we don't have to take into account the date constraint ? You  said that you already filtered the dates

Comment: Yeah something still doesn't add up. There either isn't a date constraint (you work with all the data), or there's still something we don't know.

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, take a look at the snippet at the bottom. the snapIndex is the month index from user

Comment: So let's answer this question: do you need to worry about the month, since this data was generated as a result of the user's selection? If the answer is, "you don't need to worry about it", then the solution is easy. Just group everything by category and reduce the groups.

Comment: @TimConsolazio take a look at the snippet at the bottom. the snapIndex is the month index from user. my snippet will iterate through the array and only select those who are at the selected month

Comment: Ah ok, so first you filter by month. Then you group by category. Then you reduce the groups to the category total. That sound right?

Comment: Hold on, I'm trying to construct the JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  expensesObject: [{
    amount: "10",
    category: "001",
    exactDate: ""
  }, {
    amount: "20",
    category: "002",
    exactDate: ""
  }, {
    amount: "12.5",
    category: "004",
    exactDate: ""
  }, {
    amount: "17.70",
    category: "004",
    exactDate: ""
  }]
};

//Filter to get data of the month
//obj.filter(o => moment(o.exactDate).month() === snapIndex);

console.log(obj.expensesObject.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    let v = x.category;
    let el = rv.find((r) => r && r.category === v);
    if (el) {
      el.amount += +x.amount;
    } else {
      rv.push({
        category: v,
        amount: +x.amount
      });
    }
    return rv;
  }, []));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, took me some time to implement. Absolute awesome!